# BouncyCastle PGP API: How to add user attribute packets to the key ring?

Tags: java, pgp

I am using BouncyCastle PGP library in my current project and I need to add additional packets to the my PGP Public/Secret keys (ImageAttribute, ExpirationDate and etc.).

During deep investigation of bcpg-prov.jar I've found that BC allows to do it. But I didn't find any examples in Google how can I do it.

Does anyone know how to add image and expiration date to the PGP keys using BC libraries?